# How to show internal lines in Paraview?

Tags: paraview

I made a picture of a blob in VTK. Blob consists of many triangular pyramids with their vertices in the centre of the blob.

[image]

I would like to see all lines, but Paraview hid all internal lines of the blob. Is it possible to make these lines visible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Use the Extract Edges filter. This will extract all edges in your mesh, not just the edges on the outside surface.

Comment: Thank you, helped a lot!